# How to iterate with a for loop through a dictionary and save each output in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, for-loop

How to iterate with a for loop through a dictionary and save each output of the iteration. The output from this function will be a tuple but is needed as a DataFrame.

There is a variable used in the function: n = 5

The dictionary has also n elements

So the function should be executed n-times (5-times) and should be saved n-times (5-times)

```
n = 5

x = range(0, n)

for df in x:
    df = pd.DataFrame()

        for y in range(0, n):
            for p in df:
                p = 10 * 10 * n
```

so the formula should be executed 5 times,

```
1st: n = 1
2nd: n = 2
3rd: n = 3
4th: n = 4
5th: n = 5
```

I am going to receive 5 diffrent results and these results should be stored in a DataFrame

I dont know how to save the results from each iteration of the loops.

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [ask] and then try to produce a [mcve].

Comment: There's no dictionary in the code you posted. The code contains bugs that make it unclear - for example, `df` is used as both an index in a loop *and* a dataframe. Post what your original data looks like and what the expected output is. The only result seems to be that of `100*n`.

Comment: There is no function defined in your code let alone a tuple as a return value

Comment: You need to explain more clearly what you want to do.  The code you provided does not make much sense . A Pandas DataFrame has rows and one or more columns. What exactly do you want the DataFrame content to be?

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame(i * 100 for i in range(n))` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an empty list before the loop and append the results of each iteration to that list. Then you can convert the list of tuples to a DataFrame using pd.DataFrame().

```
import pandas as pd

n = 5
results = []

for i in range(1, n + 1):
    result = 10 * 10 * i

    # Append the result to the list
    results.append(result)


df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=['Result'])


print(df)
```

Comment: Fix your code indentation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there might be a misunderstanding about dataframes and loops. In your code snippet, df is being overwritten in every iteration of the x loop with a new, empty DataFrame, and the p loop does not actually modify df because pandas DataFrames are not mutable (changeable) in the way you're trying to do.

However, based on your description, it sounds like you want to create a new DataFrame with a single column where each row contains the value of 10 * 10 * n for n in range(1, 6). Here is a way you could do that:

```
import pandas as pd

# Define n
n = 5

# create an empty list to store results
results = []

# Loop over the range
for i in range(1, n+1): #start at 1 and end at n. Range ends before the specified end value
    # Compute the result
    result = 10 * 10 * i
    # Append to the list of results
    results.append(result)

# Create a Dataframe from the results
df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=['Result'])

# Print the Dataframe
print(df)
```

This should output:

```
   Result
0     100
1     200
2     300
3     400
4     500
```